# C# Compiler Directives

Tags: c#, compiler-directives

I’m looking at some C# code, and have come across the following statement:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Do something here
#else
    // Do something else
#endif
```

I assumed that DEBUG would be a defined somewhere as follows:

```
#define DEBUG
```

But I’m unable to find such a definition, although the code seems to behave as though it were set.  Is DEBUG a special case, and if so, how is it set / unset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the project, go to `Properties -> Build`. Under general, you have an option there for defining both `DEBUG` and `TRACE`.

Comment: So what is the advantage / reasoning behind having these check-boxes rather than having #define DEBUG set?

Comment: @pm_2 - Centrality. Thats about it.

Answer (score 4):

It is set with the `#define` directive or in the [compiler settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx). It is common for DEBUG to be defined in debug releases, so you could conditionally compile some code like in your example.

You can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx).

Comment: **Please** don't post Visual Studio 2003/.NET 1.1 links! Readers follow the links, and then want to follow the links from the links, and wind up stuck in 2003.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just fixed that. Silly Google's fault and I have low-bandwidth edition enabled so I don't immediately see. All excuses of course :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the project properties you will find a debug option DEBUG
Then you can do in C#:

```
[Conditional("Debug")]
public void DebugThis()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the DEBUG and TRACE conditional compilation constants under the project Properties' Build tab. For this instance, **Define DEBUG constant** checkbox is probably checked for your project.

More details @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx).